# How to make the background gradient of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gradient, paintcomponent

I want to know how to make background gradient which is in another JPanel. Many articles found in internet,but all of them had demostrated how to overide the paintComponent() of the JPanel not how to do for a jPanel which is inside it.
I use Netbeans IDE. I created a new JPanel class and could overide its paintComponent(). I have another jpanel on it (dragged & dropped on to the parent JPanel). I want to make its background gradient.

Here is how I tried  for parent. It worked. How can I overide this for child jpanel ?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color color1 = getBackground();
        Color color2 = color1.darker();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight(); 
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                0, 0, color1,
                0, h, color2);

        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
```

Comment: You'll have to use that code in another separate class that extends `JPanel`. Afaik, there's no way for a parent component to change how its children are painted. So extend `JPanel` for your subcomponents and put the code you have here into your subpanels.

Comment: @Brian, Thanks. Is it same for other JComponents(when need to overide its methods)?

Comment: All `JComponent` classes have this [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method, so yes.

Comment: @AashMaharoon for some components you can set their background transparent using `setOpaque(false)` this way whatever the parent draws is still visible inside the child.

Answer (score 12):

If you are careful to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`, you can add the gradient directly to the panel as shown below.

For usability, I would resist the temptation to try making the individual components transparent. Note also that [opacity](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#props) is controlled by the Look & Feel.

[image: GradientPanel]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
* @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12220853/230513
*/
public class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final int N = 32;

    public GradientPanel() {
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(N, N, N, N));
        this.add(new JLabel("Test:", JLabel.CENTER));
        this.add(new JTextField("This is a test."));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color color1 = getBackground();
        Color color2 = color1.darker();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
            0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GradientPanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GradientPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. What you have mentioned is already implemented for my parent JPanel( the codes also mentioned in my question). What I ask is, lets say, if *another JPanel* is required to add to your 'GradientPanel'. and make its background gradient. Then how it can be done ?

Comment: Ah, you want to alter the background of a `JPanel` for which you do not have source code access. You could use `UIManager.put()` to supply your own `PanelUI` with a custom implementation of `paint()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying to do

```
jPanel1 = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                int w = getWidth();
                int h = getHeight();
                Color color1 = new Color(81,80,106);
                Color color2 = new Color(165,164,241);
                GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
                g2d.setPaint(gp);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            }
        };
```